# I am trying to pass formControlName to the child component in angular but facing some issues to bind the form, please find the below snippets

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

```
data-table.html (parent component)
```

this is the parent component where i will be using some generic components, and i would want to bind that component to the reactive form.
    ```</hello>-->

Start editing to see some magic happen :)

````
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <form [formGroup]="userForm">
    <mat-table formArrayName="users" #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let rowIndex = index" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
          <span *ngIf="!isEdit"> {{element.position}} </span>
          <span *ngIf="isEdit"><input type="text" formControlName="no"></span>
        </mat-cell>

      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let rowIndex = index" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
          <span *ngIf="!isEdit"> {{element.name}} </span>
          <span *ngIf="isEdit">  <app-custom-dropdown [fieldControlName]="this.userForm.controls.users.controls[rowIndex].get('name').value" [fieldIndex]="rowIndex" 
          [fieldFormGroup]="userForm"></app-custom-dropdown></span>
        </mat-cell>

      </ng-container>

      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let rowIndex = index" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
          <span *ngIf="!isEdit"> {{element.weight}}</span>
          <span *ngIf="isEdit"><input type="text" formControlName="weight"></span>
        </mat-cell>

      </ng-container>

      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let rowIndex = index" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
          <span *ngIf="!isEdit"> {{element.symbol}} </span>
          <span *ngIf="isEdit"><input type="text" formControlName="symbol"></span>
        </mat-cell>

      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
  </form>
  <p>{{userForm.value | json}}</p>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onEdit()">Edit</button>
</div>
```

custom-dropdown.component.html (child component)
````

This is the generic component where i am getting the formGroup and the formControl from the parent component and binding it to the template, as suggested

````
```
<div [formGroup]="fieldFormGroup">
    <ng-select [items]="cities" appendTo="body" formControlName="fieldControlName" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select city">
    </ng-select>
</div>
``

custom-dropdown.component.ts
```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-custom-dropdown",
  templateUrl: "./custom-dropdown.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./custom-dropdown.component.scss"]
})
export class CustomDropdownComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  @Input() fieldControlName;
  @Input() fieldIndex;
  @Input() fieldFormGroup;
  cities = [
    { id: 1, name: "Hydrogen" },
    { id: 2, name: "Helium" },
    { id: 3, name: "Pavilnys", disabled: true },
    { id: 4, name: "Lithium" },
    { id: 5, name: "Oxygen" }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.fieldControlName);
    console.log(this.fieldIndex);
  }
}
```
when i am trying to execute this code i am getting the below error
**ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'fieldControlName'
    at _throwError (forms.js:3357)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:3181)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:7345)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:8070)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7993)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31906)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
**


Please help me in which part i am doing mistakes here..
````

Comment: If you provide a minimal repro with a stackblitz project I might be able to help you out

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your template to make it a property binding expression instead string value assignment :

```
<div [formGroup]="fieldFormGroup">
    <ng-select [items]="cities" appendTo="body" [formControlName]="fieldControlName" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select city">
    </ng-select>
</div>
```

`formControlName="fieldControlName"` this assigns to `formControlName` property `"fieldControlName"` string literal.

`[formControlName]="fieldControlName"` this binds `formControlName` property to `fieldControlName` property.

**Edit :**
To fix your `formControlName` binding in your template. You just need to pass the controlName it should be enough to make it work.

```
<span *ngIf="isEdit">  <app-custom-dropdown fieldControlName="name" [fieldIndex]="rowIndex" 
          [fieldFormGroup]="userForm"></app-custom-dropdown></span>
```

This time we will use string assignment instead property binding. You don't need to explicitly find the exact control to bind it.

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let rowIndex = index" [formGroupName]="rowIndex">
```

The line above already specifies the `formGroupName`. So children of this component will know which formGroum it belongs to.

Comment: Thanks Eldar, after doing so i am getting an error Cannot find control with name: 'Helium'.. am i still missing something in the code please??

Comment: I have Updated my template as below..
```<div [formGroup]="fieldFormGroup">
    <div [formArrayName]="fieldArrayName">
        <div [formGroupName]="fieldIndex">
            <ng-select [items]="cities" appendTo="body" [formControlName]="fieldControlName" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select city">
            </ng-select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @shams  `[fieldControlName]="this.userForm.controls.users.controls[rowIndex].get('name').value"` this part is dangerous. You need to create a `formControl` that matches the value of the `name`. And basically it is hard to achieve so. You need a different approach there.

Comment: any suggesions how would i be binding the form with the child component please?